# geolocation.getCurrentPosition on PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

I made an app using PhoneGap that needs to access the user's current latitude and longitude to function.
Here's what I did:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    // code using pos
});
```

On the browser this asks your permission to access the info, but on the finished app it doesn't ask anything and just doesn't work.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 0):

@Dogmatics,
there is not enough information to debug your problem. Assuming you turned on the GPS and Location services, then you forgot to wait for the 'deviceready' event.

From the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready):

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova function.

If this proves to be correct, you will want to read #4 in:
*Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md

Best of Luck

Comment: Yes, I understand I didn't give much to work with, but then again, I didn't either. I didn't know about the deviceready event, that must be it.
With that in mind should I keep using jQuery(document).ready() or should I change that to deviceready?